# Which takes less memory/processing power? UUID's or Strings?

Tags: java

Which would take less memory to store and less processing power to use, UUID's, or a string of say 10 characters?

Comment: I would say "it doesn't matter", because you should use whichever is the most appropriate for your application. The speed/memory difference is not likely to matter..

Comment: Given that Bohemian is simply correct, I would like to ask: "Why do you want to know?" The only reason I can think of is that this has something to do with a runtime environment that is very limited in resources, in which case your tags and question are probably very much not complete.

Answer (score 3):

From Java APIs :

[UUID](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html)

> A UUID represents a 128-bit value.

[String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

> A String represents a string in the UTF-16 format

UTF-16 can be represented by either 16 or 32 bits (it depends on the character). So for 10 characters, `UUID` will definitely use less memory.

I don't know about processing though.