# Is there any benefit to using UUID over String for storing them in Android development?

Tags: android, uuid

I pass some guids over from my backend for my android app. I could easily go on with life and just treat it as a String. I never actually generate guids on the front-end, as there is no need. I treat them as guids in my database for storage purposes, but beyond that, it becomes very cumbersome on the Android side to pass my guid around as a UUID instead of a String.

Are there any benefits?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which takes less memory/processing power? UUID's or Strings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22765048/which-takes-less-memory-processing-power-uuids-or-strings)

Answer (score 1):

Just two.  One is a performance boost you can do on your own if you wish (it stores UUIDs as multiple integers, speeds up comparisson).  The main purpose of the UUID class is to generate new ones.  The other is extra expressiveness-  it makes it more explicit for later maintainers.